# Upload video to youtube playlist in php

Tags: php, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I am trying to find how to use youtube data api v3 playlist functionalities but I am unable to find anything on the internet. your help will be highly appreciated and I will be very helpful to you.

Comment: Welcome, Please add your code, and refer for asking better questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Please give us information about what you already tried along with some code.
People usually post here when they are stuck with an issue with their code. without it, we can't help much.

Anyway, you should start here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3 and there https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list